# change the background color of the application from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently using an architecture where I have multiple fragments that I swap in the same activity.
I need to be able to use a different background color for one of these fragments BUT I don't want to use the lazy solution that adds one layer of overdraw.
For clarity : I have a window background setted by my theme and on top of it I draw cards & lists. In one of my fragments I need a slightly different window background color.
Is there any way to do that ? I already tried to use a ContextThemeWrapper but it does not seem to work (maybe because the background has already been drawed ?)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you want to change it dynamically at runtime or statically at compile time?

Comment: Dynamically.
I have a structure comparable to the Play Store with a nav drawer that switches between multiple fullscreen (minus the actionbar) fragments.  One of these fragments need to use a different background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it :

It is doable by calling

```
    ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                R.color.your_color));

    getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(cd);
```

during the initialization of your fragment, when it is attached to the activity.

Comment: Using the window's background is a bad idea for multiple reasons. For one it causes an overdraw that you thought you were avoiding. For more information see here: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html

Comment: @EricBarr on the contrary, it avoids adding overdraw : I already have a window background and just wanted to change its color for one of my fragments. I edited the question & answer for more clarity.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately changing a fragment's background at runtime isn't supported. To get this functionality you can wrap your fragment inside of a RelativeLayout or something similar and set the background programmatically on that.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ccc">
    <fragment android:name="whatever.fragment.name"
            android:id="@+id/frag_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your code get by id fragmentContainer1 and do `view.setBackgroundColor(YourColorVariable)` on it.

Another way may be to get your fragment, find the root view, then set the background on that. `fragment.getRootView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)` This depends on your fragment's layout though, so it may or may not work.

Comment: Thanks, but this adds a layer (and the associated overdraw) to my view hierarchy, so it is not an option.

Comment: What does your fragment layout look like? The "Another way" option may work for you.

Comment: sorry to downvote you, but there are just too many people that add a layer in their layout for this purpose.